# Does having a lot of null objects drain memory? and if so is there an alternative to using ArrayDeque as a queue?

Tags: java, memory, queue

I'm a n00b so I'm sorry if I'm way off with this one but I am using arraydeque as a queue for some threads to process.  Each thread processes the an item in the queue(each thread checks if there's data in the queue and if it is it does queue.poll(), if its good then its  sent away in a solution queue otherwise the data it is either discarded or a part of it is sent back to the queue for further processing.

Here's my problem, the longer my program works the more memory it keeps using and eventually I get outofmemory errors(but it stays maxed out for a while before this happens).  I'm learning java so I'm not sure if I have identified this correctly but I ran yourkit on my code and it said:

```
Find arrays with big number of 'null' elements.
Problem: Possible memory waste.
Possible solution: Use alternate data structures e.g. maps or rework algorithms.
```

yourkit also showed me that 93% of my memory was stuck in here(in the heap dump). Yesterday I asked a question about arraydeque.polling() being a possible memory hog and got a comment saying that it was not because my data is turned into 'null' once its polled.

So my two questions(as in my title) is having a constantly growing number of null objects a problem(I am not sure if they get GC'ed but since there was several million in the heap dump, I suspect maybe not)? If so, is there an alternative to ArrayDeque, maybe something that GC's items when they are no longer needed(my program is constantly processing and adding items in a queue, but even though the number of items to process is reduced the memory consumption never goes down, when the program is done is just suddenly goes to zero, if the queue is gradually building I would expect it to gradually get smaller)?

Another slightly related question, I'm dealing with a few billions of items in a queue thats being processed by threads, but memory is causing it to fail.  Is there a point to me trying to improve my internal program queue or would it make more sense to use a real queue program like(rabbitmq or activemq)?(I'm really new to program so not sure when I reached a limit of a tool and how to either improve it or figure out what to use next)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ArrayDeque` stores items in a flat array with a help of two "*pointers*" - head and tail. If the total number of elements in the queue exceeds the current size of this array, its size is doubled.

When you poll an item from the queue, the slot in this array is cleared (set to `null`), but the array never really shrinks! This means if you first offer million items to the queue and then poll all of them, there `ArrayDeque` still maintains an array of at least 1 million entries, all of them set to `null`. This explains the *Find arrays with big number of 'null' elements* message.

Seems like your application at some point in time offers huge number of elements to the queue. Try (periodically?) calling the following code:

```
queue = new ArrayDeque<String>(queue);
```

This will copy the contents of old `queue`, garbage collecting unnecessarily big internal array.

Note that there is no such thing as a *null object* - if you removed an item from the queue and this item is no longer referenced by your code - it will be garbage collected.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like the `ArrayDeque` implementation never shrinks its internal array, so it just keeps growing forever. When an object is polled from the deque, its corresponding array element is set to `null`, and the object will eventually be garbage-collected (if all other references to it disappear as well). But the internal array in `ArrayDeque` just keeps growing.

The `Deque` interface is also implemented by `LinkedList` and `ConcurrentLinkedDeque`, so you're probably best off using one of those.